# Hyphenated sub project names with new sbt 0.13 multi-project definition

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to set up a [multi-project](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html) using the new sbt 0.13 (`build.sbt`). The idea that the `lazy val`'s name determines the sub project name sounds rather odd to me. Moreover, I don't get hyphenation but end up with camel case:

```
lazy val myprojectCore = project
```

When I list `> projects`, I see `myprojectCore`. How can I make this `myproject-core`?

---

Also, what the purpose and relationship of the `name` key now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone is looking for this now, with sbt `1.x` series we can do the following.

```
lazy val myprojectCore = project.withId("myproject-core")
```

Answer (score 5):

I am guessing the recommended approach is to use camel case to unify towards Scala identifiers.

I don't have solid evidence on the preference, but the fact that `project` picks up the variable name from the left-hand side and also the fact that setting keys too use camel case in the shell made me think so. The relationships among sbt, Maven, and scala projects are rather complicated. Despite multiple efforts to make sbt builds, scala/scala project has always used Ant to build for example. In any case, Maven artifacts should probably be hyphenated, and for that you could use `name` key.

I could write:

```
val scalaxbPlugin = project.in(file("sbt-scalaxb")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
    sbtPlugin := true,
    name := "sbt-scalaxb",
    description := """sbt plugin to run scalaxb"""
  ).
  dependsOn(app)
```

Here's what I had before:

```
val scalaxbPlugin = Project("sbt-scalaxb", file("sbt-scalaxb")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
    sbtPlugin := true,
    description := """sbt plugin to run scalaxb"""
  ).
  dependsOn(app)
```

Comment: Alright, I can use the `Project.apply` constructor instead of `project`, that's fine. I am curious though—do you have any information that camel case is preferred now? Because to my knowledge 99.9% of Maven artifacts use hyphenation. Including scala-org stuff (scala-library, scala-compiler, scala-swing, etc. pp.)

Comment: Yes, camel case is preferred for the reason Eugene states.  The ID of a project is mainly used for referring to the project from code and at the command line.  Use `name`, as Eugene suggests, to specify a human readable name for the project.  This is used in various places a human readable name is expected, such as the scaladoc title.  This name then gets normalized to `normalizedName`, but you can override that.  This normalized name is used for things like Maven artifacts.  `inspect` will help see what is used where.  Unfortunately, there are many variations of names!

Answer (score 3):

The previous answers pretty much nailed it down fully, but one really needs to read between the lines to get the gist of it.

I use sbt `0.13.1`.

### Code Analysis

Let's start by consulting the source code of sbt.

From `sbt.Project` (with some formatting):

```
/**
 * Creates a new Project.
 * This is a macro that expects to be assigned directly to a val.
 * The name of the val is used as the project ID and 
 * the name of the base directory of the project.
 */
def project: Project = macro Project.projectMacroImpl
```

The `project` macro's implementation is pretty much as the scaladoc says. It resolves to the following code where `project-name` is the name of the project.

```
Project([project-name], new File([project-name]))
```

So, whatever Scala itself accepts is acceptable as a project name.

Regarding the `name` setting.

From `sbt.Keys`:

```
val name = SettingKey[String]("name", "Project name.", APlusSetting)
```

In `sbt.Defaults`' `projectCore` method:

```
name := thisProject.value.id
```

with

```
val thisProject = SettingKey[ResolvedProject]("this-project",
            "Provides the current project for the referencing scope.", CSetting)
```

It should give you the idea of how the `project` macro affects the project name and vice versa.

### Example

Given the following `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val `hey-hoo` = project in file(".")
```

in a directory, sbt console gives:

```
jacek:~/sandbox/stackoverflow/proj1
$ sbt
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/stackoverflow/proj1/project
[info] Set current project to hey-hoo (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/stackoverflow/proj1/)
[hey-hoo]> show this-project
[info] Project(id: hey-hoo, base: /Users/jacek/sandbox/stackoverflow/proj1, aggregate: List(), dependencies: List(), configurations: List(compile, runtime, test, provided, optional))
[hey-hoo]> show name
[info] hey-hoo
[hey-hoo]> projects
[info] In file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/stackoverflow/proj1/
[info]   * hey-hoo
```

Answer (score 2):

One possibility:

```
lazy val `myproject-core` = project
```

But is this the way to do it?

Comment: You could, but then you have to refer to it as `myproject-core` everywhere in your code.  Also, I think the command line would now use `myproject$dashcore` or something like that.

Comment: It works on the command line, e.g. `myproject-core/test:run` _does_ work this way. You are right about the first thing, I have to use backticks throughout the build file.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar project structure and created project/Build.scala. I'll include my complete file below. Note that the id="mod-overlay", etc settings. These result in the following for me:

```
> projects
[info] In file:/Users/randolph.kahle/development/source/stash/arch/overlays/
[info]   * arch-overlay
[info]     mod-overlay
[info]     mod-overlay-doc
[info]     mod-overlay-test
```

Here is the Build.scala file:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object ProjectBuild extends Build {
  lazy val root = Project(
    id = "arch-overlay",
    base = file(".")
  ) aggregate(moduleOverlay, moduleOverlayDocumentation, moduleOverlayTest)

  lazy val moduleOverlay = Project(
    id = "mod-overlay",
    base = file("urn.org.netkernelroc.mod.architecture.overlay")
  )

  lazy val moduleOverlayDocumentation = Project(
    id = "mod-overlay-doc",
    base = file("urn.org.netkernelroc.mod.architecture.overlay.doc")
  )

  lazy val moduleOverlayTest = Project(
    id = "mod-overlay-test",
    base = file("urn.org.netkernelroc.mod.architecture.overlay.test")
  )
```

Comment: Thanks Randy, I did use the `project/Build.scala` approach before, and indeed you can specify project IDs there. But in the `build.sbt` file it seems you don't have a setter for the project ID.

Comment: You can use `lazy val root = Project(...)` in `build.sbt` and you can use `lazy val root = project` in `Build.scala`.  A `.sbt` file is basically just standard Scala expressions and definitions, but with some default imports and without requiring the enclosing `object ProjectBuild ...` part.

Comment: Just to add to @MarkHarrah's comment above - `project` is just a macro  that expands to the reified `Project(name, new File(name))`.

Comment: I am using this variant now, in regular `build.sbt` which works the same.